# Querying the database passing multiple parameters rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, querying

I have a user table and an activity table. The user has many activities. This is what i have in my users table:

```
class SorceryCore < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
create_table :users do |t|
    t.string :first_name
    t.string :surname
    t.integer :previous_award
    t.integer :chosen_award
  t.string :email,            :null => false
  t.string :crypted_password
  t.string :salt

  t.timestamps
end

add_index :users, :email, unique: true
end
```

This is what I have in my activities table:

```
class CreateActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
create_table :activities do |t|
  t.integer :activity_type
  t.string :activity_name
  t.string :approver_email
  t.references :users, index: true, foreign_key: true

  t.timestamps null: false
end
end
```

In my view I want to show the activity_name, where user_id = the current user's id, and where the the activity_type = 1. I'm not sure where to write this method or how to call it either. I have read through the following link but can't seem to get anything working. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

I think I need to use something along the lines of this:

```
Activity.where("activity_type <= ?", 1).where("user_id <= ?", current_user.id)
```

But I'm not sure if this is supposed to go into a method in the controller or the model, and I'm not sure which controller or model it's supposed to go into

Answer (score 0):

In the User model:

```
# user.rb
def activity_by_type(type = 1)
  self.activities.where(activity_type: type).first
end
```

and then, you can call `current_user.activity_by_type(<specify the type here>)`

You can use the above method to get any of the activity type for the specified user, by specifying the type in the method call.

One advice I'll give though is to try and use [the concept of enums](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to categorize your `activity_type` column in the activities table. An example on how, [can be found here.](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/creating-easy-readable-attributes-with-activerecord-enums/)

Comment: Thanks, but I seem to be getting an error: undefined method 'activity'

Comment: can you tell me where you are getting that error? or the full error message?   Also, I made an edit to my answer. can you cross check that you are using the latest version of the answer?

Comment: Below is the error from the terminal:
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `activity' for #<User:0x007ff60f0c0348>):
   
     8: 
     9:             <h1><%= current_user.setCommunity %></h1>
    10:         <h4><%= current_user.activity_by_type(1) %></h4>
    11: 
    12:         
    13:         <span><%= current_user.first_name %></span>
  app/models/user.rb:9:in `activity_by_type'
  app/views/activities/community_home.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_activities_community_home_html_erb___3535737252128861255_70347348235740'

Comment: Thanks for the update, I am now using enums to categorise my types. I have 3 types personal, physical and community. Not really sure how that affects what I'm doing here though - how can enums help here? As for the error, I’m quite new to rails, so I don’t really understand the it

Comment: oh, shoot! it should be `self.activities`, not `self.activity`. as user `has_many`, and not `one` activities. I have updated the answer. As for enums.... In a word, it makes life easier. :)

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: activities.user_id: SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."user_id" = ? AND "activities"."activity_type" = ?  ORDER BY "activities"."id" ASC LIMIT 1):
     9:             <%= current_user.setCommunity %>
    10:         <h4><%= current_user.activity_by_type(3) %></h4>
    11:  <span><%= current_user.first_name %></span>
  app/models/user.rb:9:in `activity_by_type'
  app/views/activities/community_home.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_activities_community_home_html_erb___3535737252128861255_70347348235740'

Comment: that is interesting. as you have a `t.references :users` in your migration for activities table. can you confirm the attributes on an Activity object?

Comment: i can confirm them in the rails console, but not sure how to do that in the application really.

Comment: Yes, in console. can you check if there is a `user_id` on activities

Comment: I can see that there are user_ids in the activities table if thats what you mean?

Comment: haa.. I see it now. it should be `user_id`, not `user_ids`. the problem is from your migration: `t.references :users` should be `t.references :user`. so, to solve this, generate another migration, to change that column name from `users` to `user`, and that would solve it finally. ( in short, ensure that the activities table have a `user_id` column, not a `user_ids` column. )

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to query on the `current_user.activities` association:

```
@activities = current_user.activites.where(activity_type: "1")
```

You could also use a `scope` (which is what `SunnyK` recommended):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :activities
   scope :by_type, ->(type = 1) { activities.where(activity_type: type) }
end
```

--

If you only wanted to return a single record, you'd have to replace [`.where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) with [`.find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by):

```
@activity = current_user.activities.find_by activity_type: 1
```

--

Since you're using an `enum`, you may wish to use the built-in class method that you'd be able to call:

```
enum activity_type: [:sports, :photography]

@activity = current_user.activities.sports
```

Comment: Thanks Rich - can i just ask, where should I put @activity = current_user.activities.sports? i want to basically show current_user.activities.sports.activity_name in my view but that won't work because it says undefined method 'activity_name' even though it is an activity attribute

Comment: `current_user.activities.sports` returns a *collection*, so you'd have to do `current_user.activites.sports.each do |sport| sport.activity_name end`